# How do I set value to input type text with dynamic id, using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have div element with dynamic id for input type text.

this is my html code.

```
<?php 
for($j=0;$j<=3;$j++){
?>
 <input type="text" id="money<?php echo $j; ?>"/>
<?php
}
?>
```

And this is my script. I try with this code but its not work, and the value is still empty.

```
$("#money1").val("200");
```

I try with this code and its working, but it affect all of the input type text with 'money' id.

```
$('input[id^="money"]').val("200");
```

please help me, I'm already stuck.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: If the second works then the first should also work -> Please add a [mvce] that shows the actual problem ([How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: show the code where id becomes dynamic in js here $("#money1").val("200");

Comment: I not to make dynamic id in js. I make dynamic id with looping in php. Lets assume I have html code like this.  <input type="text" id="money0"/> <input type="text" id="money1"/> <input type="text" id="money2"/> <input type="text" id="money3"/>. I want to set the value for input text with id money1 using jQuery. This my script $(function(){$("#money1").val("200"); }). But its doesnt work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The code in the question works just fine. Do you get any errors in the console when you load the page?

Comment: @El_Vanja I haven't try it in the console, maybe I must try it in console to see the errors.

Comment: I mean the [browser console](https://javascript.info/devtools). Keep it open while you're working with your page and you should see if there are any errors.

Comment: @EL_Vanja when I try in browser console there is no errors, but the value can not set to id money1

Comment: Then are you 100% sure the element ids have generated properly? When you look at the source of the page, are the ids correct (money0, money1, etc.)?